# How to use progressmeter in an XUL application?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, xulrunner

This might be a simple question for geeks, but not for me, at least. I was developing a simple **XUL** program from scratch. I used `wizard` tag to simplify the GUI that appears to the user. On a `wizard` page I have inserted a `progressmeter` to show the progress of a function called `myFunction()` which belongs to the JavaScript which is available in the XUL file. How can I properly update the `progressmeter` based on the real progress of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the progression of the progressmeter using its "value" property?

```
myProgressmeter.value = 50;
```

You just need to increment this value depending on the progression of your function.
Note that the value should be set between 0 and myProgressmeter.max

Comment: The question was **how**? I know the value attribute, and how to set a value to it. The thing is that, I need to know what is the progress of the function to set an appropriate value to the **value** attribute. The **progressmeter** on the XUL document wont get updated properly. That is the issue. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, you can set this value in from your javascript function as it progresses.

If your function is executing in a js module (and not a script) you won't have direct access to the XUL document and will need to use observers, otherwise it should work.
Note that it can be that you should use the property value and not the attribute one to set the progression. It's a common error to try updating an element through the attribute and not the property...

Comment: @revers, 

My JavaScript part is
`function progressBarUpdate(x) {
 var pgs = document.getElementById("clng_progress_bar");
 pgs.value = x;
}

function progressBar() {
 for(var i=0;i<=100;i++) {
  progressBarUpdate(i);
  for(var j=0;j<1000000;j++);
 }
}`


and the XUL part is


`<progressmeter id="clng_progress_bar" mode="determined" value="0" />`



Why don't this work as expected?

Comment: XUL processes only one event at a time. Which means that as long as your function doesn't return the UI won't be updated. Try to insert :var thread =Components.classes['@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIThreadManager).currentThread;thread.processNextEvent(true);   between 2 calls of progressBarUpdate and it should work. This tell to the current thread to process next event (user entries, GUI refresh,etc...) before processing farther. By the way for(var j=0;j<1000000;j++); seems to be optimized and not executed or to fast to have the expected delay.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? Did it solve your problem? It worked on my computer...

Comment: @revers, I have tried this. But the javascript doesn't work when I add the line `thr­ead.processNextEvent(true);` in my source code. Can you give me a working example? If possible, please send me a working code tarball. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's strange it worked without problem by me using this function. I' quite sure yur prolem is that XUL do not update the GUI as long as you do not exit the function or you do not tell him processing another operation (using the piece of code I gave you). You should look in this direction to solve your problem...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reverse thread work round does work, but as per the doc (here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIThread) `processNextEvent` may wait for a very long time if there are no pending events! Err.. since `xulrunner` is single thread there appear to be few, resulting in a huge slow down. Waggling the mouse helps though.

On further investigation `use processNextEvent(false)` works without delay.